# QBPopupMenuの実装方法について

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

下記サイトにてQBPopupMenuの実装が紹介されていますが、うまくいきません。
http://www.iosjp.com/dev/archives/tag/qbpopupmenu
手順通りにやったはずですが、「実装方法」で紹介されているコードのうち、
QBPopupMenu関係のクラスや変数がほぼ全て宣言されていませんとなってしまいます。
また、QBPopupMenu.mでは、"QBPopupMenuItemView.h"が見つかりませんと出ます。
どなたか解決方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>サポート： non- ARC</strike>

と記載があるので、ARCでは使用できないのでは無いかと思います。  
もしARCを使用されているのでしたら、試しにARCを無効にしてみては如何でしょうか？
[ファイル毎に ARC の有効・無効を設定する](http://program.station.ez-net.jp/special/objective-c/llvm/arc/enable-file.asp)

----- 最初の回答は間違っていて紛らわしいのでコメントの内容で再回答 -----

[質問のリンク先](http://www.iosjp.com/dev/archives/tag/qbpopupmenu)の実装方法は旧バージョンの実装方法のため、最新版ではエラーとなる。
最新版は[GitHubで公開](https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu)されておりDemoも一緒に用意してくれているため、ここを見れば実装方法が分かる。
QBPopupMenuは`.pch`で`UIKit`をimportしている前提で作成してあるらしく、
Xcode6以降だと多分`QBPopupMenuItem`でエラーが出る。
手動での`.pch`作成方法については[こちら](http://appstars.jp/archive/244)。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試してみたところエラーはほぼなくなりましたが、QBPopupMenu.mにて、「@implementation QBPopupMenu」の行で「ARCまたはGCモードでなければいけません」と出てしまいました。

Comment: @inu shiba 確認しましたが最新版は使い方が変わっているようです。[GitHub](https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu)のDemoを参考に実装すればできると思います。注意点として`.pch`で`UIKit`をimportしておかないと`QBPopupMenuItem`でエラーが出ます。`.pch`の追加については[Xcode6 PCHファイルがないので追加する](http://appstars.jp/archive/244)をご参照ください。

Comment: @inushiba あとARC無効化も不要でした。

Comment: すみません、ARC無効化を取り消して、.pchを追加しましたが、エラーに変化はありませんでした。最初に紹介したアドレス内の「実装方法」のコードの配置が間違えているのでしょうか？

Comment: @inushiba 2番目のコメントに記載しましたが最初のリンク先の実装方法は古いバージョンの実装方法です。GitHubのプロジェクト内に作成者の方が用意してくれているDemoがあるのでそちらを参考にした方が良いです。

Comment: 最新版のDemoを見ました。しかし、その中の「ViewController.m」内にインポートされている「QBPlasticPopupMenu.h」がわかりません。どこにこのファイルが置かれているのでしょうか？その他は全てエラーが消えました。

Comment: @inushiba GitHubの'QBPopupMenu'配下に普通にあります。Demoだけでなく元のプロジェクト内も見るようにした方が良いです。また、そもそも使わないのであれば`import`する必要もありませんので、一度Demoで動作確認をした上で、自分で取捨選択するようにした方が良いです。あとは自分で頑張ってみてください。